# How to open a file named after the value of a variable which changes across rows in SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to open a file in SAS where the name of the file changes for each row based on the value of a variable. 
All the files I want to open are in the same directory named a day of the year as a number (127.csv, 128.csv, 129.csv, etc). My SAS data has a column called "day" and for every row, I would like to open the file named that day, extract a value from that file and add it to my original file.
What is the best way to open a file when the name changes each row with the value of a variable?
See my attached [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nV4Wc.png) if this is unclear. 
Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to read out of these files?  Do you just want to read one line? All of the lines? Do all of the files have the same structure?

Comment: What is the header line of the csvs ? Are they consistent ? What is the "a value" being extracted ? Is it more than on value ?  Read the documentation for `INFILE` option `FILEVAR` and update the question after you write some code.

Comment: Why pipe the file name at all? Any reason to not just mass read all the files at once and then filter? We're more than happy to help, but it's much easier when you show an attempt or approach. Otherwise, what we post isn't usually relevant because we're missing key information, like you need to do this for X groups or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general if you want to drive reading a set of files from a list you use the `FILEVAR=` option on the `INFILE` statement.

```
data want;
  set have ;
  length fname $200 ;
  fname = catx('/',"&path",cats(day,'.csv'));
  infile csv filevar=fname dsd firstobs=2 end=eof truncover ;
  do while (not eof);
    input ..... ;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Put whatever code you need to read the CSV file(s) inside the DO loop. Make sure to use the OUTPUT statement to explicitly write out the observations since each iteration of the data step will process one whole file.